# how to pass variable to next page and access it using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
      var radioValue = $("input[name='ans']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue){
            alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
        }
    });

});
```

This is my script to check which radio button is selected, the value will be stored on radioValue, I want to pass this to second page ,which contains modal with some fields, and access this value in second page.

Comment: you can store it in session or in database.

Comment: `window.location = 'someurl?myvariable=' + radioValue` then just access it from the URL.

Comment: [**Please search before posting.**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+pass+variable+to+next+page) More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: I don't want to use session because using javascript i can't  directly access the value.